# Input in Functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I ask for user input in the nthroot function? I want the function to ask input for the power of x and the next term. (I want the program to ask for power and next term, I only used 3 and 81 respectively as a check)

```
def derivative(f, x, h):
   return (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2.0*h)  

def nthroot(x):
   return x**3 - 81   # just a function to show it works


def newraph(f, x0, h):
   Xold = x0
   Xnew = Xold + 10* h  
   while (abs(Xold - Xnew) > h):  
      Xold = Xnew 
      Xnew = Xold - f(Xnew) / derivative(f, Xold, h)  #NewtonRaphson formula
   return Xnew

trueroot = newraph(nthroot, 1, 0.000001)    
print "The root is", trueroot
```

When I tried using the int(raw_input()) like this  :

```
def derivative(f, x, h):
  return (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2.0*h)  

def nthroot(x):
   root = int(raw_input("Please Enter a nth root (n) : "))
   number =  int(raw_input("Please Enter a number (x): "))
   return x**(root) - (number)

def newraph(f, x0, h):
   Xold = x0
   Xnew = Xold + 10* h  
   while (abs(Xold - Xnew) > h):  
      Xold = Xnew 
      Xnew = Xold - f(Xnew) / derivative(f, Xold, h)  #NewtonRaphson formula
   return Xnew

trueroot = newraph(nthroot, 1, 0.000001)    
print "The root is", trueroot
```

The prompt for the input repeats several times. How do you end that?

Comment: I can't image that what you describe really happens.

Comment: you probably call `nthroot` several times, hence it asks user more then once. Please include parts where you actually call `nthroot`

Comment: Why are you complicating the difference quotient?

Comment: I've edited the code, also what I meant with my last sentence is, I input the "root" and "number" but after inputting it asks for me to input those 2 again.

Comment: It's because of the recursion, define your root function with concrete numbers or take input globally outside of the function.

Comment: Thanks @Malik-Brahimi, I didn't realize to put the input outside. Beginner mistake I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try generating your Nthroot function on the fly with the wanted values already in there. These values will then be reused in every vall to "f" in newraph.

This method will allow you to keep using arbitrary functions for newraph (even ones where you don't need user input or completely different inputs).

```
def derivative(f, x, h):
  return (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2.0*h)  

def generateNthrootFunc():
   root = int(raw_input("Please Enter a nth root (n) : "))
   number =  int(raw_input("Please Enter a number (x): "))
   def nthroot(x):
      return x**(root) - (number)
   return nthroot

def newraph(f, x0, h):
   Xold = x0
   Xnew = Xold + 10* h  
   while (abs(Xold - Xnew) > h):  
      Xold = Xnew 
      Xnew = Xold - f(Xnew) / derivative(f, Xold, h)  #NewtonRaphson formula
   return Xnew

root = newraph(generateNthrootFunc(), 1, 0.000001)    # call the solver
print "The root is", root
```

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to put the lower part of the code.

Comment: Adapted my answer :-).

Comment: Thanks! I saw also that I could just input outside :D though this one looks better!

Comment: Yup, that would be the slightly less complicated solution. If that works for you, you could just use that (always use the solution you understand the best that suits your needs :D).

Answer (score 0):

> *The prompt for the input repeats several times...*

That's becouse you're calling the function several times:

```
root = newraph(nthroot, 1, 0.000001)    # call the solver
```

end then inside `newraph`

```
while (abs(Xold - Xnew) > h):  
  Xold = Xnew 
  Xnew = Xold - f(Xnew) / derivative(f, Xold, h)  #NewtonRaphson formula
```

where `f` is `nthroot`.

Then you call it agin in `derivate` (twice):

```
def derivative(f, x, h):
  return (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2.0*h)
```

### Posible solution

You could make `nthroot` a class

```
class nthroot_generator:
    def __init__(self, number, root):
        self.number = number
        self.root = root
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x**(self.root) - (number)
```

and callit like this:

```
root = int(input("Please Enter a nth root (n) : "))
number =  int(input("Please Enter a number (x): "))
trueroot = newraph(nthroot_generator(root, number), 1, 0.000001)
```